# How to put items in an array to the object next to it in a json format in python?

Tags: python, json, object, arraylist

I have a file of hundreds of json schemas that I need to parse through and fix the schema format in a way that the "isRelatedto" property will have an object(dictionary) without the extra strings outside the object. Also, with the strings that startswith "pubmed", I want to change it to "pmid" and then insert it into the object inside of "isRelatedto" array(list). The problem I have is that some of the "isRelatedto" array has object and some of them do not as shown below. When I tried to use the code I wrote to make the change, the schema without an object does not change. I would really appreciate your help!

```
      "isRelatedto": [
        "pubmed:18984613",
        "pubmed:25392406",
        "pubmed:33147627"
      ]
      
    
      "isRelatedto": [
        "pubmed:20947564",
        "pmcid:PMC3013774",
        {
          "@id": "https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkq901",
          "@type": "sc:CreativeWork"
        }
      ]
```

The expected result for the first one will be:

```
"isRelatedto": [
       {
        "pmid": "18984613",
        "pmid": "25392406",
        "pmid": "33147627"
       }
      ]
```

and for the second one will be:

```
"isRelatedto": [
       {
         "@id": "https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkq901",
         "@type": "sc:CreativeWork"
         "pmid": "20947564"
       }
     ]
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. You can't have `key:value` pairs outside an object delimited with `{}`

Comment: In your first expected result, what you have is a list, not a dictionary.  You have the wrong kind of brackets.  And you can't make it a dictionary, because you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Yeah, the original JSON is what I adapted from someone else, and I'm trying to fix it to put all key:value inside an object. But the old file has key:value outside of an object (which they are being treated as strings now in an array). @Barmar

Comment: Unless everything is broken in a consistent way, you'll be very unlikely to be able to parse it reliably.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for me to make everything consistently? For example, to put all key:value inside an object?